# During the mission "Hunting the Archon", what is the impact of choosing to save the Salarians over the Krogan?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Near the end of the mission "Hunting the Archon", while you're aboard the Archon's ship you're contacted by the Salarian path finder who has found more Salarians cornered off and unable to escape, while simultaneously being contacted by a team of Krogan scouts who had turned up uninvited.

Due to the long history between the Krogans and the Salarians this choice seems like it would be one that carries significant weight and has lasting repercussions.

What is the impact of choosing to save the Salarians over saving the Krogan?

Comment: Spoilers! Cmon guys

Comment: the game sadly spoils itself. If you want to avoid spoilers don't get 100% viability before completing the story otherwise you'll be like what are all of these settlements apparently cheering for my victory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you decide to save Salarians and kill Krogan, Pathfinder Raeka will be present during the final run against the Archon. If Raeka is killed (aka you didn't save her), her place will be taken by the captain of Salarian ship (as he is next in line to be the pathfinder). Then he will appear at the end run.

As far as Krogan go, if you save them Drack will be happy, saying "Finally Krogan aren't pushed aside". If not, he will say Raeka "You better be worth it" and later both him and Kesh during the meeting with Nexus staff will show discontent.